# How do you diagnose an external hard drive that shows zero byte size?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

A few days ago my external HDD dropped from the shelf. It is ADATA HD710 1TB USB drive. Now, when I connect it to my PC, it doesn’t show up in Windows Explorer. I can see it in DiskPart, though. In DiskPart, the disk is shown but with **zero byte size**, and no partitions on it. Trying to create a partition returns an error.

Ruled out:
 - I have tested this drive on multiple computers and with another cable with no success. (The drive is powered by single usb cable.)
 - Uninstalling the driver and obtaining new driver from Windows update didn't help.

To me, it seems the head is stuck or malfunctioning. Or, maybe the PCB or SATAtoUSB adapter is damaged. The data on the drive is expendable, but I need the drive. I can’t afford to buy a new one.

It’s file system was NTFS. I ran the clean command in DiskPart. So, the partition should now be removed. But creating a new partition returns an error shown in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot of DiskPart]

Comment: I'd say the drive is toast. If you have a desktop PC, you can try removing it from the enclosure and connecting to a spare SATA port on your desktop motherboard to eliminate the USB controller as an issue.

Comment: *you cant afford to continue using that drive* Any data you put on it is at high risk if being lost. 1tb drives are hardly expensive now (I could *give* you one from a pile im throwing away after replacing it with SSD - maybe you can open the drive, check that the usb-> sara interface works then scrounge an internal 2.5" drive to replace it.  If you happen to live in NZ let me know how I can contact you)